# minimize WPF application into Taskbar

Tags: wpf

I am using [This WPF NotifyIcon](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon#closing) and all works fine:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon
    Name="taskbarIcon"            
    IconSource="icon.ico"
    ToolTipText="hello world">
</tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

But when minimize my application i can see the application open and not only the `Icon` in the `Task Bar`.
How to hide the application when minimize ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the StateChangingEvent

Add this code in your Window's Constructor

```
StateChanged += (s, e) => if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized) Hide();
```